# INetgear aircard AC763S., how do I install it?

Tags: 16.04

Please give me a # I can call.  I have a netgear hotspot that I can't get to work on my pc. I had it working beautifully but it stopped for whatever reason??   I still have internet on my phone so the the hotspot contraption does work.  It's just that Telus has no one that knows how to hook up Linux to netgear.  How stupid.  My phone 357-0131

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide further info after collecting same as described here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos